# 'Not a function' error with setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am trying to make a function run 60 times per second. So I've declared `setInterval(this.updateAt60, 1/60*1000);` in this class' constructor.

This is the function that should be called repeatedly:

```
LightingScene.prototype.updateAt60 = function(){
   this.controlSubmarine();
   this.submarine.setPosition();
}
```

Yet, I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: this.controlSubmarine is not a function` and I can call it everywhere on the code except on there. The order of function declaration is constructor/ controlSubmarine/ updateAt60.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are missing the context of `this`

Comment: try this one. setInterval(this.updateAt60.bind(this), 1/60*1000);

Comment: use `requestAnimationFrame` not `setInterval`